# Problemas con Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wpf

Buen día, tengo el siguiente error a la hora de guardar los datos de un formulario en la Base De Datos. trabajo con C# y WPF.

Esta es la excepción:

```
System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: 'Validation
failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for
more details.'
```

Comment: Muestra el codigo que te da error

Comment: Debes ahondar más en la pregunta colega... pero por el tipo de error que mencionas, alguna de las propiedades de un objeto que estas utilizando no paso una de las validaciones asignadas por ti.. esta podría ser de tipo Required, MaxLength, etc etc etc... pero como te mencione, para poder ayudarte de una mejor forma debes contextualizarnos mejor =)

Comment: Mira por favor [ask]. Tu pregunta necesita trabajo para ser contestada...